# Fill in a $5 \times 5$ square to make equal products in rows and columns

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, puzzle

Let's say you fill in a $5 \times 5$ square with $1, 2,\dots, 25$. Is there a way to fill it so that the product of the first row is equal to the product of the first column, the product of the second row is equal to the product of the second column, etc?

What about generalization for a $n \times n$ square filled with $1, 2,\ldots, n^2$?

---

Edit: Here are some updates on progress. For $n=3$, it is a possibility:

$$\begin{matrix} 5 & 1 & 6\\
                 2 & 7 & 4\\
                 3 & 8 & 9\end{matrix}$$

I'm not sure how to do $n=4, 5$. I know that if there are $>n$ prime number between $n^2/2$ and $n^2$ then $n$ doesn't work. I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You're talking about multiplicative magic squares: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicationMagicSquare.html  As far as I know, there are none for consecutive $k = 1,2...n\times n$

Comment: I edited and added clarification to my question. @above I believe for $n=3$ there is possibility.

Comment: Oh, with your edit I noticed you're not looking for a full magic square, but just each row matching its respective column. Interesting. But I think you're on the right track thinking about primes. For $n=3$, $5$ and $7$ have to be on the diagonal; $3$ doesn't because there are other numbers with $3$ in their prime factorization. But for, $n=4$, since you only have two numbers with a factor of $7$, you'd need $7,11,13,14$ on the diagonal, and that'll fill up fast. For $n=5$, you need $11,13,17,19,22,23$ all on a diagonal. Edit: given what I said for $n=4$, what other numbers make it impossible?

Comment: For $n=4$, could you please provide explanation for why 7 is on diagonal? Would it not work if 7 and 14 are symmetric about diagonal?

Comment: If $n = 4$ you can put $7= i,j$ but then you need $14$ in the $(j, x)$ row *AND* in the $(y,i)$ column so that requires $7= i,j$ and $14 = j,i$.  *OR* it would require both $7, 14$ along the diagonal.  But of $n = 5$ then you must place $7, 14$ and $21$.  If $n = 5$ then $11,13,17,19,23$ are in the diagonal so $7, 14, 21$ or none an the diagonal and that leads to a contradiction.  If $n=4$ then $13,11$ are in the diagonal where do we put $3,6,12,15$... okay $9$ is along the diagonal. But were to we put the $8$ ... $n=4$ might be possible but $n=5 $ si not.

Comment: Why 11 is in the diagonal for $n=5$? Can not we have 11 and 22 diagonally symmetrical?

Comment: Also asked on [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/107606/20814)

Comment: @fleablood For n=5 we not necessarily have 7, 14 or 21 in the diagonal. They could be at positions (1,2),(2,3) and (3,1), then the rows 1,2,3 and columns 1,2,3 each have a 7 factor. Also 11 don't  need to be on the diagonal.

Comment: FYI:  This question was previously closed for being a current PROMYS admission problem (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33257/request-to-keep-an-eye-out-for-promys-admissions-problems?cb=1), and it was reopened today because the application deadline has passed.  My answer (yes, it's possible) was deleted when the question was closed.  Perhaps a moderator can undelete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution:
$$
\matrix{
7 & 18 & 14 & 10 & 5 \\
24 & 13 & 11 & 6 & 15 \\
21 & 22 & 17 & 12 & 4 \\
1 & 20 & 9 & 19 & 8 \\
25 & 3 & 16 & 2 & 23
}
$$
The row and column products are 88200, 308880, 376992, 27360, and 55200.  You can easily modify this by applying an arbitrary permutation to both the rows and the columns, applying another arbitrary permutation to the diagonal entries, and/or taking the transpose.

How I found it:  The primes 13, 17, 19, and 23 only appear once each, so they must all go on the diagonal.  I made the last diagonal entry 7 because $25!$ equals $7 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 23$ times a square, although I don't think this was actually necessary.  (For example, the three multiples of 7 could appear in positions $(1, 2), (2, 3)$, and $(3, 1)$, instead of putting one on the diagonal and the other two symmetrically around it.)  Then, by trial and error, I found a way to place the multiples of 5 so that each row and corresponding column are divisible by 5 with the same multiplicity.  After this, I placed the 1 and 3 near the bottom left to make the row-product-to-column-product ratios nice, and did the rest by more trial and error.

Update:  Here's a solution for the 4x4 version, found by a similar method (but with much less casework):
$$
\matrix{
1 & 9 & 8 & 4 \\
3 & 5 & 7 & 12 \\
6 & 14 & 11 & 10 \\
16 & 2 & 15 & 13
}
$$
I'll let you attempt the cases $n = 6, 7, 8$, and $10$, which seem to be the only other cases not ruled out by primes between $n^2/2$ and $n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.... $\prod_{k=1}^{25} = 2^{24}3^{10}5^6c7^3*11*13*17*19*23$

The odd prime powers must be distributed along the diagonals.  For example if $11$ is the $k$th row then the product of the $k$th row is divisible by $11$ so the product of the $k$th column is divisible by $11$ but $11$ is the only cell divisible by $11$ so $11$ must appear in the $k$th row of the $k$th column.

So the $5$ cells in the diagonals must be $11,13,17,19,23$.  But where will put the $7, 14,$ and $21$?.  If we put $7$ in the $n$th row and $m$th column, $ n \ne m$ , then the $m$th row and the $n$th column will both need multiples of $7$.  BUt we only have three such multiples total.

If we put a multiple of $7$ in the $m$th row and $n$ column we have one extra unclaimed one.  An if we put it in the $m$th row $j$ column $j\ne m, j\ne n$ the we need a fourth one int the $j$th row.

So not possible.

And the for and

Comment: I do not think you are correct. First, $25!$ is divisible by $11^2$ because $11$ and $22$. Second, you are incorrect with regard 7, 14, and 21. Consider to have 21 on row 1 column 2, 14 on row 2 column 3, and 7 on row 3 common 1. That disprove yours solution, no?

Comment: Dang nab it.  Of course $22= 2\times 11$.  So $11$ *isn't* along the diagonal. And ... row 1, so column 1. Column 2 so row 2. column ... dag nab it!